# Is Asterisk Operator for Set type documented?

Tags: delphi, syntax, vcl

I cannot understand what this code is doing and I found no documentation about it.

```
if FComponentState * [csDesigning, csInline] = [csDesigning, csInline] then
```

Comment: `if ([csDesigning, csInline] <= FComponentState) then` is a way to test a subset. Unfortunately the `in` operator does not allow a set argument, otherwise `if ([csDesigning,csInline] in FComponentSet) then` would be easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the  `*` operator represents the intersection of two sets and is documented [in the official documentation of Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Set_Operators) (see *Set Operators*).

Answer (score 3):

The set intersection operator `*` has been part of Pascal since its inception.

This particular example checks that both elements are present in the set.

Comment: I was searching wrong: First I typed "*", then operator, then set, haha, I was not even close.

Comment: This is true, but what about the question that was asked?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already `*` gives the intersection of two sets.

`if FComponentState * [csDesigning, csInline] = [csDesigning, csInline] then` checks if both `csDesigning` and `csInline` are in FComponentState.
It does so by first getting the intersection between `FComponentState` and `[csDesigning, csInline]` and than verify that it is the same as `[csDesigning, csInline]`.